# Troubleshooting simple create-from

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to read a value from a view in aps.net mvc: I am aware that this seems like a very basic issue, however, i could not find any solution for this, so i am turning to you: In my case, it seems as if the parameter playlistModel.Model.Name is never sent, or at least is null.

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PlaylistViewModelDetails playlistModel)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(playlistModel.Model.Name))
    {
        //this is never called due to playlistModel.Model.Name being null.
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(playlistModel);
}


@model Orpheus.Models.ViewModels.PlaylistViewModelDetails
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Erstellen" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}


public class PlaylistViewModelDetails
{
    public PlaylistModel Model = new PlaylistModel(); //a seperate class containing a string value, which must be read from the form
}
```

Thank you for helping me to solve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PlaylistViewModelDetails` contains only a field for `Model`. The `DefaultModelBinder` only binds properties, not fields.

Change your model to

```
public class PlaylistViewModelDetails
{
    public PlaylistModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

and add a parameter-less constructor if you want to initialize `PlaylistModel`

```
public PlaylistViewModelDetails()
{
    Model = new PlaylistModel();
}
```

Note also `Name` in `PlaylistModel` also need to be a property.